# SqlDataSource filter on conditional dropdownlist values

Tags: filtering, webforms, sqldatasource

i have 3 dropdownlists that i need to filter my datasource at runtime.

Each of the dropdownlists must be combined with the other two BUT they also have a 'special' value of "*ALL*". in this case i want to disable filtering on the specific filed and show all values.

Does this come with some out of the box functionality from asp.net or i have to build the string every time ?

Answer (score 0):

After searching in many places i finally found out that there is NOT an out of the box functionality of asp.net to dynamically build WHERE clauses based on the values of every control that i want to participate in filtering.

I ended up with custom coding on the gridview selectedindexchanged event that builds the selectcommand text and binds the gridview again.

works fine!